# Google maps API - multiple locations on multiple maps in one page

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

we have to use google map for map location. For different maps with multiple locations in one page. Is it possible?

Actually we want multiple maps, but in google api code they give us one map for one page, how we can change and make this multiple maps.

google API link:- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex

code:-

```
// google map section
function initMap() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
 zoom: 15,
 center: {lat: 35.9099, lng: 14.4498}
});
setMarkers(map);
}

// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
// order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
var beaches = [
  ['Property 3', 35.9065598, 14.4502898, 3],
  ['Bondi Beach', 35.9099206, 14.4498855, 2],
  ['Coogee Beach', 35.9159643, 14.4484053, 1]
];
```

Please check Code Link:- [Jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/bharat_negi/0r4bfs41/2/)

First is show multiple location, second map not show any location.

Comment: Use as many elemts you want and create maps its not map corresponds to container `document.getElementById('map')` add more container add m ore maps

Comment: I try this but not working for one page.

Comment: Can you share that piece of the code? Maybe embed it in jsfiddle.

Comment: Show us the code how you tried was each map a new instance?

Comment: @BharatNegi check my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass two variables to your `setMarkers` function since you're creating two maps, you need to initialize two variables `map` and `map1` and then call `setMarkers(map, map1);`.

In `setMarkers` function, you need to set two markers now, second marker will need the `map` option set to `map1`.

```
var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
      map: map1,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
```

**UPDATED ANSWER:**

```css
#map, #mapTwo{width: 300px; height: 500px; }
#map {float:left;}
#mapTwo {float:right;}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>

<div id="mapTwo"></div>

<script>
// google map section
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: 35.9099, lng: 14.4498}
  });
  
  
  var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapTwo'), {
    zoom: 15,
    center: {lat: 35.9099, lng: 14.4498}
  });

  // modified to pass two variables, both map instances. 
  setMarkers(map, map1);
}

// Data for the markers consisting of a name, a LatLng and a zIndex for the
// order in which these markers should display on top of each other.
var beaches = [
  ['Property 3', 35.9065598, 14.4502898, 3],
  ['Bondi Beach', 35.9099206, 14.4498855, 2],
  ['Coogee Beach', 35.9159643, 14.4484053, 1]
];


// SECOND MAP LOCATIONS
var beaches2 = [
  ['Property - MAP 2', 35.9065598, 14.4512898, 3],
  ['Bondi Beach - MAP 2', 35.9099206, 14.4598855, 2],
  ['Coogee Beach - MAP 2', 35.9159643, 14.5484053, 1]
];

function setMarkers(map, map1) {
  // Adds markers to the map.

  // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y where the origin of the image
  // (0,0) is located in the top left of the image.

  // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker increase in the X
  // direction to the right and in the Y direction down.
  var image = {
    url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
    // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
    size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
    // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
  };
  // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon. The type defines an HTML
  // <area> element 'poly' which traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points.
  // The final coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first coordinate.
  var shape = {
    coords: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18, 1],
    type: 'poly'
  };
  for (var i = 0; i < beaches.length; i++) {
    var beach = beaches[i];
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
      map: map,
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  } 
  
  // second map markers
  for (var i = 0; i < beaches2.length; i++) { 
    var beach = beaches2[i];
    // markers for second map
    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: beach[1], lng: beach[2]},
      map: map1,  // make sure to point to your second map
      icon: image,
      shape: shape,
      title: beach[0],
      zIndex: beach[3]
    });
  }
} 
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAWAoxTVd_zUi11jJe9TEvu6MUoOfzTerE&callback=initMap"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but we want different location on both map not same.

Comment: @BharatNegi create another array of locations and pass that into `marker1`. Currently, your code doesn't even show markers on the second map. Give me the location for second map and I will update my code.

Comment: @BharatNegi run the jsFiddle, now you will see varying locations on both maps. I entered random locations. You will need to zoom out on second map to see all three locations.